# My SharedPreferences shows only invisible text

Tags: android, layout, preferences, invisible

I've generated a SharedPreferences screen in my application following instructions "by the book". Nothing special. But I get only invisible preferences on screen (both simulator and phone).

Here's the screenshots (sorry, it's link. i'm not allowed to post image):
[Print Screens of Properties](http://img10.imageshack.us/i/errormd.png/)

Notice that I tried with default Theme and also Light - No Title

Here's the code:
XML/preferences.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http: //schemas. android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/menukad">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="menukad12"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:title="Nikud in the Text?"
        android:summary="@string/menukad" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
                        android:title="Checkbox Preference"
                        android:defaultValue="false"
                        android:summary="This preference can be true or false"
                        android:key="checkboxPref" />
</PreferenceCategory>       

</PreferenceScreen>
```

myPreferences.java

```
    package com.android.orvishua.mishneTorah;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class myPreferences extends PreferenceActivity 
{   
    @Override    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);    
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            chapterSave.setReLoad(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Reading preferences:

```
public SharedPreferences myprefs;
public boolean menukad; 


         myprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()) ;
        menukad = myprefs.getBoolean("menukad12", false);
```

Manifest (all other Activities are with the default style. no changes):

```
<activity android:name=".myPreferences" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".myPreferences" android:theme="@android:style/Theme_Light_NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Can someone help me???

Comment: Do you actually have spaces in `xmlns:android="http: //schemas. android.com/apk/res/android` or is that just an effect of copying? If so remove the spaces from the xmlns.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own theme in your styles.xml (if you dont have one, create it in the values folder)

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="YourStyle" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/Widget.ListView</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget" parent="android:Widget">
</style>

<style name="Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@color/gray_division</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">2dip</item>       
</style>
</resources>
```

I hope this helps